# Skipping time points in autoregressive modeling?

Tags: regression, time-series, autoregressive

Is it possible to skip immediately preceding time points? So that, if, for example, you are using model order 2, that is, two time points, but not the two immediately previous time points, but rather, say for example, skipping 2 points, and then using those two points. So, e.g., it would be y=x(t-3) + x(t-4).  What is it called? How is the "model order" distinguished from the "skipping"? Can anyone point me to it anywhere in the literature?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done time-series analysis in a while, so I can't call out specific packages, but....

You might be able to calculate this lagged differencing manually and pass it to your modeling software.

Comment: You could move this to the original thread (thus delete here) of which this one seems to be a duplicate.